# Using dynamic external urls in StaticImage in Gatsby

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-image

I'm trying to display couple of images from array of objects containing images urls. I'm aware that StaticImage has to accept local variables as props values. These two variables for image urls are both local.
Why is this not working and is there a workaround?

```
import React from 'react';
import { StaticImage } from 'gatsby-plugin-image';

const TestPage = (props) => {
  const itemData = [
    {
      img: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1549388604-817d15aa0110?w=161&fit=crop',
      title: 'Bed',
    },
    {
      img: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1563298723-dcfebaa392e3?w=161&fit=crop',
      title: 'Kitchen',
    },
  ];

  const testSrc = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1523413651479-597eb2da0ad6?w=161&fit=crop';
  const testSrc2 = itemData[0].img;

  return (
    <>
      <StaticImage src={testSrc} alt="works" />
      <StaticImage src={testSrc2} alt="doesn't" />
    </>
  )
}

export default TestPage;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you said, there's a [restriction in the  component](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-plugin-image/):

> **Restrictions on using `StaticImage`**
>
> The images are loaded and processed at build time, so there are
> restrictions on how you pass props to the component. The values need
> to be statically-analyzed at build time, which means you can’t pass
> them as props from outside the component, or use the results of
> function calls, for example. You can either use static values, or
> variables within the component’s local scope. See the following
> examples:

In your case, a plain assignation works but an object assignation doesn't. Change it to:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StaticImage } from 'gatsby-plugin-image';

const TestPage = (props) => {
  const testSrc = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1523413651479-597eb2da0ad6?w=161&fit=crop';
  const testSrc2 = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1563298723-dcfebaa392e3?w=161&fit=crop';

  return (
    <>
      <StaticImage src={testSrc} alt="Bed" />
      <StaticImage src={testSrc2} alt="Kitchen" />
    </>
  )
}

export default TestPage;
```